# How to use @import inside php stylesheet?

Tags: php, css, import

I created stylesheet with .php extension for some reason.
**on style.php**

```
<?php
/*** set the content type header ***/
/*** Without this header, it wont work ***/
header("Content-type: text/css");

$color = '#ff0000';
$path = 'http://mysite.localhost.com/includes/css/';
?>
//this works
body {
    background-color:<?=$color?>;
}
 //these don't work
@import url("<?=$path?>foundation.css");
@import url("<?=$path?>app.css");
```

I don't understand why @import doesn't work at all.

Even with plain url without variable, it doesn't work.

```
@import url("http://mysite.localhost.com/includes/css/foundation.css");
```

I wan previously used .css file. But I unable to use php variable/constant to replace the url like this.

**on style.css**

```
@import url("<?php $path?>style.css");
```

Comment: Instead of using PHP, you should try SASS or LESS.

Comment: Can you browse to http://mysite.localhost.com/includes/css/foundation.css?

Comment: @mayersdesign, can browse

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in you browsers developer console to see it those files are being requested at all?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, just checked and those css files not requested

Comment: Have to ask... have you cleared the cache?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, yes did

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try another**

```
   <?php
    $css = file_get_contents('CSS/style.css');
    echo $css;
    ?>
```

Comment: this works, thanks a lot.. I'm just trying to understand why @import doesn't work here?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
<style>
    <?php include 'CSS/style.css'; ?>
    </style>
```

Comment: header("Content-type: text/css"); already tells its a stylesheet, thus no need to use <style> tag

Comment: I'm quite sure the OP is including the file as css-file (<link rel="" ....) since the question states that all other css declarations actually work. `<style>` is used in html documents, not in external css-files.